# Extraer el texto de una pagina desde un archivo pdf sin perder el formato del archivo original en .Net core

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, itextsharp, itextpdf

tengo un requerimiento en el que me piden abrir un archivo PDF, leerlo y extraer ciertas palabras para gurdarlas en base de datos. He buscado mil maneras y cada vez que leo y abro el archivo pdf para extraer texto measigna sin formato, es decir, pierde el formato original y para mi caso necesito extraer solo los titulo (Mayusculas y Negritas) pero diferentes no tengo palabras exactas y/o definidas solo que seas Titulos dentro del pdf
He ejecutado el siguiente codigo de mil maneras con diferentes librerias open source pero todas me extraen el texto sin formato, alguien conoce alguna manera de leer y buscar directamente en el archivo pdf sin tener que asignarlo a una variable string, ya que al pasarlo me elimina el formato y no puedo encontrar los titulos

```
string filePath = @"\\" + dominioPublico + "\\" + path + "\\" + numBoletin + "___" + numTomo;

 // Crear un objeto StringBuilder para almacenar los títulos encontrados
        using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filePath))
        {
            // Recorrer todas las páginas del PDF
            for (int i = 1518; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                // Crear un objeto PdfTextExtractor para extraer el texto de la página actual
                string pageContent = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);

                // Buscar la palabra en el contenido de la página
                if (pageContent.Contains("LA PROPIEDAD INTELECTUAL - REGISTRO DE LA PROPIEDAD INDUSTRIAL"))
                {
                        // Obtener los titulos de la página
                        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(pageContent, @"\*\*(.*?)\*\*");

                        // Agregar el título al objeto StringBuilder
                        titles.AppendLine(matches[0].Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Esta es una excelente lectura que debes de realizar ya que esto ya lo han intentado realizar antes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28068493/15298643